# Goole App Script HTML Onclick Button Issue

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I am working on a sidebar menu, and so far, I got it working to load values from a sheet.  I am working on getting the sidebar to update the value that is selected and currently struggling a little bit since I can't seem to catch an error and struggling a bit to figure out how to error handle app scripts and HTML in app scripts.  So the first ask here is can someone point me to a reference on how to error handle issues with HTML and Apps script.

My second issue my current problem, I have an HTML button that is calling `onFormUpdate()` function which is located inside a seperate HTML file just for handling javascript functions.  Here is my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <base target="_top">
  <?!= include('sidebar/sidebarcss'); ?>

  <body>
    <div id="title"> 
      <div><h2>Meeting Item</h2></div>
    </div>

    <div id="meet">
      <form id="meetform">
        Row ID: <br>
        <input type="text" id="meetrowId" name="meetrowId" maxlength="4" size="4" readonly />
        Meet ID: <br>
        <input type="text" id="meetId" name="meetId" maxlength="8" size="10" readonly />
        Enter Date: <br>
        <input type="text" id="meetingDate" name="meetingDate"/>
        Topic: <br>
        <input type="text" id="meetTopic" name="meetTopic"/>
        Agenda: <br>
        <textarea name="meetAgenda" id="meetAgenda" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
        Comment History:<br>
        <textarea name="meetComments" id="meetComments" rows="10" cols="30" readonly ></textarea>
        Add Comments:<br>
        <textarea name="meetComUpdate" id="meetComUpdate" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea><br>

         <input type="button" class="button" value="Update Record" onclick="onFormUpdate()"/>

      </form>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Select Another ID" onclick="google.script.run.showEmailSidebar()"/>
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()"/>
    
    <?!= include('sidebar/script'); ?> 
    <script>
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).SidebarActiveRow();
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Within the form i call my onFormUpdate() and nothing happens when I click the button. As you can see i include 'sidebar/script' which is my html file that stores all javascript functions.  OnFormUpdate() is located within the 'sidebar/script' and is shown below:

```html
<script>
 
  function onSuccess([cellrow, meetid, meetdate, meettopic, meetagenda, meetcomments]) 
  {

    /*
    Secondary method for string parsing
    const table =sidebarVar.split(",") //["key:value","key:value"]
     .map(pair => pair.split(":")); //[["key","value"],["key","value"]]

    const result = Object.fromEntries(table);
    result.meetid;
    */
    
    document.getElementById('meetrowId').value = cellrow
    document.getElementById('meetId').value = meetid
    document.getElementById('meetingDate').value = meetdate
    document.getElementById('meetTopic').value = meettopic
    document.getElementById('meetAgenda').value = meetagenda;
    document.getElementById('meetComments').value = meetcomments;


  }


  function onFormUpdate()
  {

    var recordform = 
    {
        row: document.getElementById('meetrowId').value,
        topic: document.getElementById('meetTopic').value,
        agenda: document.getElementById('meetAgenda').value,
        newcomment: document.getElementById('meetComUpdate').value
    };

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(SidebarActiveRow).recordUpdate(recordform);
    


  }



</script>
```

As you can see I am trying to get the app handler to call `SidebarActiveRow` which is leverage with my `onSuccess` function to load data elements from the sheet; this works fine.   The handler is calling `SidebarActiveRow` to run after i successfully run `recordUpdate()` which is located in my code.gs file.  So far nothing is happening.  I have this current code for testing to see if the function works but no success.

```
function recordUpdate(recordform) {

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(recordform.row);

}
```

I get no prompts which I can't seem to troubleshoot since the html and Apps Script function don't really show an errors.  I did go to executions to see if there were any errors and i don't see any at this time.  So i am looking for some help here.

Comment: Is SidebarActiveRow a server side function or a clientside function?

Answer (score 2):

Look at javascript [Error Handling](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp).

For HTML:

```
<script>
function someFunction() {
  try {
    // ... do some code
  }
  catch(err) {
    alert(err);
  }
}
</script>
```

For App Script

```
function someFunction() {
  try {
    // ... do some code
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);  // check execution log
  }
}
```

Comment: Your troubleshooting examples and links were very helpful thank you!!  Based on the error handling, I was able to figure out that my onFormUpdate() call OnSucess was wrong.  I was able to update accurately to fix the issue.  If anyone wants to see the code change, let me know I will update it.